# GWT - google visualisation api

Tags: javascript, gwt, google-visualization, javascript-framework, chap-links-library

Is GWT (google web toolkit) the same as google visualisation API?

I want to know is this example writen in GWT: http://almende.github.io/chap-links-library/js/timeline/examples/example15_mobile.html

becouse I know that GWT is almost "death" and I want to use anularJS framework in this example if possible...

Comment: 'GWT is almost "death"'? If you mean it is almost dead, you might want to mention that to the thousands of Googlers and the hundreds of thousands of outside users that update to each version when it is released. Not to mention the dozens of speakers and hundreds of attendees present at http://gwtcreate.com/...

Comment: google left gwt and create angular

Comment: Google made Closure, and GWT, and Dart, three languages/compilers to create better web apps. Google made the closure library and angular as well as others to help grow the JS ecosystem. There is more than one way to solve any given problem, they like to find all of them. Google has members on the GWT steering committee, and a team of people continuing to work on improving GWT. When Google created Chrome OS, did that mean the end of Android OS?

Comment: IS google visualisation API part of GWT?

Comment: There is some support for the Visualization API in GWT, but it is rather outdated.

Comment: does angular suport visualisation API?

Comment: The *example* you referenced is written in GWT, but the API is just a JS API, and could be written in raw JS or GWT or Dart, but it would be all the same to your consuming code no matter the choice. At a glance it *appears* to be raw JS (perhaps with Closure?), but with compiled JS, it isn't always easy to tell. So - does it matter what language your phone OS is written in to write apps, or your browser to build web pages? Does it matter how the API is authored, provided it works? And if, heaven forbid, Google releases an updated app, now with more GWT (Sheets, Groups), is that a bad thing?

Comment: As for your new question "does angular suport visualisation API?", the API is written in JS, so anything that can call JS code will work with the visualization API, so yes, code that uses AngularJS can also use the Google Visualization API.

Comment: view-source:http://almende.github.io/chap-links-library/js/timeline/examples/example15_mobile.html - this is not a GWT example ... why you say that this example is written in GWT???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is GWT (google web toolkit) the same as google visualisation API?

no.

GWT is a development toolkit to build web applications in Java.

Google Visualisation API is a library to draw charts in your browser, available for both JavaScript and GWT.